# Is it possible to tweak the output of clojure.test?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

I have this test:

```
(ns opengltuts.core-test
  (:use clojure.test
        opengltuts.util)
  (:import (org.lwjgl.opengl
             GL11 GL12 GL13 GL14 GL15 GL20 GL21 GL30 GL31 GL32 GL33)))

(def gl-classes [GL11 GL12 GL13 GL14 GL15 GL20 GL21 GL30 GL31 GL32 GL33])

(deftest find-method-test
  (testing "find-method finds method in single class"
    (is (= (find-method "toString" Object)
           ["public java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()"])))
  (testing "find-method finds all methods in list of classes"
    (is (= (apply find-method "glShaderSource" gl-classes)
           (comment "Omitted a 'p' to trigger failure")
           ["ublic static void org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glShaderSource(int,java.nio.ByteBuffer)"
            "public static void org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glShaderSource(int,java.lang.CharSequence)"
            "public static void org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glShaderSource(int,java.lang.CharSequence[])"]))))
```

Now I made sure this fails, I get output like

```
lein test opengltuts.core-test

FAIL in (find-method-test) (core_test.clj:14)
find-method finds all methods in list of classes
expected: (= (apply find-method "glShaderSource" gl-classes) ["ublic static void 
org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glShaderSource(int,java.nio.ByteBuffer)" "public static void 
org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glShaderSource(int,java.lang.CharSequence)" "public static void 
org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glShaderSource(int,java.lang.CharSequence[])"])
      actual: (not (= ("public static void org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glShaderSource(int,java.nio.ByteBuffer)" "public static void 
org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glShaderSource(int,java.lang.CharSequence)" "public static void 
org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glShaderSource(int,java.lang.CharSequence[])") ["ublic static void 
org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glShaderSource(int,java.nio.ByteBuffer)" "public static void 
org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glShaderSource(int,java.lang.CharSequence)" "public static void 
org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glShaderSource(int,java.lang.CharSequence[])"]))

Ran 1 tests containing 2 assertions.
1 failures, 0 errors.
Tests failed.
```

I find this fairly unreadable. Rather than that, I would prefer output like:

```
<all that info stuff, like the name of the test>
Expected: [something]
Got: [something-else]
```

As is, I have troubles just figuring out what I was comparing with what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several popular testing frameworks for Clojure, clojure.test (which you are using) is popular though [Midje](https://github.com/marick/Midje) looks like it's output is closer to what you're looking for. Here is an example test failure:

```
FAIL at (t_core.clj:13)
    Expected: "I am a test file fact"
      Actual: 3
```

https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Migrating-from-clojure.test

Comment: I'm not sure whether I should accept this as the best answer - I do like Midje, but at the same time you really didn't answer the question of whether or not clojure.test's output is configurable...

Comment: I can't find any indication that it is configurable, so I suspect that it is not (short of rebinding it's print function or forking it)

Answer (score 10):

`clojure.test`'s reporting is configurable by rebinding the `clojure.test/report` function. This is described in the [docs for the namespace](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/test.clj). Your function will be called with a succession of event maps, each representing some phase of the test run. There's an example of generating JUnit-compatible output in the `clojure.test` source [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/test/junit.clj).